# Debugging SPFeatureReceiver

Tags: feature-activation, debugging

I have built an SPFeatureReceiver and am trying to debug it by attaching to the w3wp.exe process. No matter what I do no breakpoints are ever hit.  Here are my steps

1. Build and Package the solution
2. Execute Add-SPSolution PowerShell cmdlet to add wsp to SharePoint
3. Verify the solution is installed but not deployed in Central Admin
4. Attach Visual Studion 2010 to all w3wp.exe processes
5. Execute Install-SPSolution PowerShell cmdlet

I am expecting but no breakpoints are hit.  It does not look like symbols are loaded and I don't see anything close to my assembly in the loaded modules page of Visual Studio.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What scope is your Feature?

Comment: Scope is set to "Farm"

Comment: Did you try a direct Debug from VS2010? This will do a deploy automatically and go into debug mode. Are the features enabled?

Comment: Yes that does not work either.  When doing so the feature does get deployed because I can see the results. However it is not fully working to my satisfaction and seeing it in debug mode should clear things up for me.

Comment: Tried an IIS reset in between adding the solution and attaching the debugger?

Comment: Yes I have and the result is the same.  Nothing breaking.  I see th msg in my source code next to the breakpoint indicating that No symbols are loaded for this document and I am not sure how to get them loaded.

Comment: Here is a good resource with tips on SP debugging: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2008/06/11/SharePoint-Debugging-and-Logging-Tips-and-Tricks.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install-SPSolution starts a SharePoint Timer process, so try attaching to the owstimer process instead of w3wp.

Comment: Good idea but attempting to do that yields this error even though i am building in Debug mode.

"The following module was built either with optimizations enabled or without debug information.

To debug this module, change its project build configuration to Debug mode. To suppress this message, disable the 'Warn if no user code on launch' debugger option."

Comment: Try adding this line of code to the top of your method: System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch

Comment: Adding this to the constructor worked!
#if DEBUG
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
#endif

Answer (score 5):

According to this post [How to debug Feature Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793780/sharepoint-2010-feature-receiver-code-executed-from-ui-not-from-powershell-or-s) you can add this line of code to the method you are trying to debug:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer ***Laurie***..... Its is work for me.... :)